# pagination "next" link is not working properly

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

pagination is working well.. but the next link is not working in  proper manner and  pervious link also not showing when i click on next link it produces this
result of next link is http://127.0.0.1/work/client/home/index/5
but again i click on next link it stuckes there.

```
        $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config = [

      'base_url'                 =>     base_url('client/home/index'),

      'per_page'                 =>     5,

      'total_rows'               =>    $this->client->num_rows(),

   ];

    $config['full_tag_open']     =      '<ul class="pagination">';

    $config['full_tag_close']    =      '</ul>';

    $config['num_tag_open']      =      '<li class="page-item">';

    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li><a>';

    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';

    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';

    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item disabled">';

    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';

    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';



    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['transactions'] = $this->service_model->transactions_table_model($com_id, $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
```

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot access your localhost...

Answer (score 0):

replace pagination library PATH  system/library/pagination.php

```
class CI_Pagination {

/**
 * Base URL
 *
 * The page that we're linking to
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $base_url = '';

/**
 * Prefix
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $prefix = '';

/**
 * Suffix
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $suffix = '';

/**
 * Total number of items
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $total_rows = 0;

/**
 * Number of links to show
 *
 * Relates to "digit" type links shown before/after
 * the currently viewed page.
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $num_links = 3;

/**
 * Items per page
 *
 * @var int
 */
public $per_page = 10;

/**
 * Current page
 *
 * @var int
 */
public $cur_page = 0;

/**
 * Use page numbers flag
 *
 * Whether to use actual page numbers instead of an offset
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $use_page_numbers = false;

/**
 * First link
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $first_link = '&lsaquo; First';

/**
 * Next link
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $next_link = '&gt;';

/**
 * Previous link
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $prev_link = '&lt;';

/**
 * Last link
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $last_link = 'Last &rsaquo;';

/**
 * URI Segment
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $uri_segment = 0;

/**
 * Full tag open
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $full_tag_open = "<ul class='pagination'>";

/**
 * Full tag close
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $full_tag_close = "</ul>";

/**
 * First tag open
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $first_tag_open = '<li>';

/**
 * First tag close
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $first_tag_close = '</li>';

/**
 * Last tag open
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $last_tag_open = '<li>';

/**
 * Last tag close
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $last_tag_close = '<li>';

/**
 * First URL
 *
 * An alternative URL for the first page
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $first_url = '';

/**
 * Current tag open
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $cur_tag_open = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";

/**
 * Current tag close
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $cur_tag_close = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";

/**
 * Next tag open
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $next_tag_open = '<li>';

/**
 * Next tag close
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $next_tag_close = '</li>';

/**
 * Previous tag open
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $prev_tag_open = '<li>';

/**
 * Previous tag close
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $prev_tag_close = '</li>';

/**
 * Number tag open
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $num_tag_open = '<li>';

/**
 * Number tag close
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $num_tag_close = '</li>';

/**
 * Page query string flag
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $page_query_string = true;

/**
 * Query string segment
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $query_string_segment = 'page';

/**
 * Display pages flag
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $display_pages = TRUE;

/**
 * Attributes
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_attributes = '';

/**
 * Link types
 *
 * "rel" attribute
 *
 * @see CI_Pagination::_attr_rel()
 * @var array
 */
protected $_link_types = array();

/**
 * Reuse query string flag
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $reuse_query_string = true;

/**
 * Use global URL suffix flag
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $use_global_url_suffix = true;

/**
 * Data page attribute
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $data_page_attr = 'data-ci-pagination-page';

/**
 * CI Singleton
 *
 * @var object
 */
protected $CI;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param   array   $params Initialization parameters
 * @return  void
 */
public function __construct($params = array()) {
    $this->CI = & get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->language('pagination');
    foreach (array('first_link', 'next_link', 'prev_link', 'last_link') as $key) {
        if (($val = $this->CI->lang->line('pagination_' . $key)) !== FALSE) {
            $this->$key = $val;
        }
    }

    $this->initialize($params);
    log_message('info', 'Pagination Class Initialized');
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Initialize Preferences
 *
 * @param   array   $params Initialization parameters
 * @return  CI_Pagination
 */
public function initialize(array $params = array()) {
    isset($params['attributes']) OR $params['attributes'] = array();
    if (is_array($params['attributes'])) {
        $this->_parse_attributes($params['attributes']);
        unset($params['attributes']);
    }

    // Deprecated legacy support for the anchor_class option
    // Should be removed in CI 3.1+
    if (isset($params['anchor_class'])) {
        empty($params['anchor_class']) OR $attributes['class'] = $params['anchor_class'];
        unset($params['anchor_class']);
    }

    foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
        if (property_exists($this, $key)) {
            $this->$key = $val;
        }
    }

    if ($this->CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE) {
        $this->page_query_string = TRUE;
    }

    if ($this->use_global_url_suffix === TRUE) {
        $this->suffix = $this->CI->config->item('url_suffix');
    }

    return $this;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Generate the pagination links
 *
 * @return  string
 */
public function total_rows() {
    return $this->total_rows;
}

public function create_links() {
    // If our item count or per-page total is zero there is no need to continue.
    // Note: DO NOT change the operator to === here!
    if ($this->total_rows == 0 OR $this->per_page == 0) {
        return '';
    }

    // Calculate the total number of pages
    $num_pages = (int) ceil($this->total_rows / $this->per_page);

    // Is there only one page? Hm... nothing more to do here then.
    if ($num_pages === 1) {
        return '';
    }

    // Check the user defined number of links.
    $this->num_links = (int) $this->num_links;

    if ($this->num_links < 0) {
        show_error('Your number of links must be a non-negative number.');
    }

    // Keep any existing query string items.
    // Note: Has nothing to do with any other query string option.
    if ($this->reuse_query_string === TRUE) {
        $get = $this->CI->input->get();

        // Unset the controll, method, old-school routing options
        unset($get['c'], $get['m'], $get[$this->query_string_segment]);
    } else {
        $get = array();
    }

    // Put together our base and first URLs.
    // Note: DO NOT append to the properties as that would break successive calls
    $base_url = trim($this->base_url);
    $first_url = $this->first_url;

    $query_string = '';
    $query_string_sep = (strpos($base_url, '?') === FALSE) ? '?' : '&amp;';

    // Are we using query strings?
    if ($this->page_query_string === TRUE) {
        // If a custom first_url hasn't been specified, we'll create one from
        // the base_url, but without the page item.
        if ($first_url === '') {
            $first_url = $base_url;

            // If we saved any GET items earlier, make sure they're appended.
            if (!empty($get)) {
                $first_url .= $query_string_sep . http_build_query($get);
            }
        }

        // Add the page segment to the end of the query string, where the
        // page number will be appended.
        $base_url .= $query_string_sep . http_build_query(array_merge($get, array($this->query_string_segment => '')));
    } else {
        // Standard segment mode.
        // Generate our saved query string to append later after the page number.
        if (!empty($get)) {
            $query_string = $query_string_sep . http_build_query($get);
            $this->suffix .= $query_string;
        }

        // Does the base_url have the query string in it?
        // If we're supposed to save it, remove it so we can append it later.
        if ($this->reuse_query_string === TRUE && ($base_query_pos = strpos($base_url, '?')) !== FALSE) {
            $base_url = substr($base_url, 0, $base_query_pos);
        }

        if ($first_url === '') {
            $first_url = $base_url . $query_string;
        }

        $base_url = rtrim($base_url, '/') . '/';
    }

    // Determine the current page number.
    $base_page = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? 1 : 0;

    // Are we using query strings?
    if ($this->page_query_string === TRUE) {
        $this->cur_page = $this->CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment);
    } elseif (empty($this->cur_page)) {
        // Default to the last segment number if one hasn't been defined.
        if ($this->uri_segment === 0) {
            $this->uri_segment = count($this->CI->uri->segment_array());
        }

        $this->cur_page = $this->CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);

        // Remove any specified prefix/suffix from the segment.
        if ($this->prefix !== '' OR $this->suffix !== '') {
            $this->cur_page = str_replace(array($this->prefix, $this->suffix), '', $this->cur_page);
        }
    } else {
        $this->cur_page = (string) $this->cur_page;
    }

    // If something isn't quite right, back to the default base page.
    if (!ctype_digit($this->cur_page) OR ( $this->use_page_numbers && (int) $this->cur_page === 0)) {
        $this->cur_page = $base_page;
    } else {
        // Make sure we're using integers for comparisons later.
        $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
    }

    // Is the page number beyond the result range?
    // If so, we show the last page.
    if ($this->use_page_numbers) {
        if ($this->cur_page > $num_pages) {
            $this->cur_page = $num_pages;
        }
    } elseif ($this->cur_page > $this->total_rows) {
        $this->cur_page = ($num_pages - 1) * $this->per_page;
    }

    $uri_page_number = $this->cur_page;

    // If we're using offset instead of page numbers, convert it
    // to a page number, so we can generate the surrounding number links.
    if (!$this->use_page_numbers) {
        $this->cur_page = (int) floor(($this->cur_page / $this->per_page) + 1);
    }

    // Calculate the start and end numbers. These determine
    // which number to start and end the digit links with.
    $start = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;
    $end = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;

    // And here we go...
    $output = '';

    // Render the "First" link.
    if ($this->first_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page > ($this->num_links + 1 + !$this->num_links)) {
        // Take the general parameters, and squeeze this pagination-page attr in for JS frameworks.
        $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, 1);

        $output .= $this->first_tag_open . '<a href="' . $first_url . '"' . $attributes . $this->_attr_rel('start') . '>'
                . $this->first_link . '</a>' . $this->first_tag_close;
    }

    // Render the "Previous" link.
    if ($this->prev_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page !== 1) {
        $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $uri_page_number - 1 : $uri_page_number - $this->per_page;

        $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, ($this->cur_page - 1));

        if ($i === $base_page) {
            // First page
            $output .= $this->prev_tag_open . '<a href="' . $first_url . '"' . $attributes . $this->_attr_rel('prev') . '>'
                    . $this->prev_link . '</a>' . $this->prev_tag_close;
        } else {
            $append = $this->prefix . $i . $this->suffix;
            $output .= $this->prev_tag_open . '<a href="' . $base_url . $append . '"' . $attributes . $this->_attr_rel('prev') . '>'
                    . $this->prev_link . '</a>' . $this->prev_tag_close;
        }
    }

    // Render the pages
    if ($this->display_pages !== FALSE) {
        // Write the digit links
        for ($loop = $start - 1; $loop <= $end; $loop++) {
            $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $loop : ($loop * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;

            $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, $loop);

            if ($i >= $base_page) {
                if ($this->cur_page === $loop) {
                    // Current page
                    $output .= $this->cur_tag_open . $loop . $this->cur_tag_close;
                } elseif ($i === $base_page) {
                    // First page
                    $output .= $this->num_tag_open . '<a href="' . $first_url . '"' . $attributes . $this->_attr_rel('start') . '>'
                            . $loop . '</a>' . $this->num_tag_close;
                } else {
                    $append = $this->prefix . $i . $this->suffix;
                    $output .= $this->num_tag_open . '<a href="' . $base_url . $append . '"' . $attributes . '>'
                            . $loop . '</a>' . $this->num_tag_close;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Render the "next" link
    if ($this->next_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page < $num_pages) {
        $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $this->cur_page + 1 : $this->cur_page * $this->per_page;

        $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, $this->cur_page + 1);

        $output .= $this->next_tag_open . '<a href="' . $base_url . $this->prefix . $i . $this->suffix . '"' . $attributes
                . $this->_attr_rel('next') . '>' . $this->next_link . '</a>' . $this->next_tag_close;
    }

    // Render the "Last" link
    if ($this->last_link !== FALSE && ($this->cur_page + $this->num_links + !$this->num_links) < $num_pages) {
        $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $num_pages : ($num_pages * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;

        $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, $num_pages);

        $output .= $this->last_tag_open . '<a href="' . $base_url . $this->prefix . $i . $this->suffix . '"' . $attributes . '>'
                . $this->last_link . '</a>' . $this->last_tag_close;
    }

    // Kill double slashes. Note: Sometimes we can end up with a double slash
    // in the penultimate link so we'll kill all double slashes.
    $output = preg_replace('#([^:"])//+#', '\\1/', $output);

    // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
    return $this->full_tag_open . $output . $this->full_tag_close;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Parse attributes
 *
 * @param   array   $attributes
 * @return  void
 */
protected function _parse_attributes($attributes) {
    isset($attributes['rel']) OR $attributes['rel'] = TRUE;
    $this->_link_types = ($attributes['rel']) ? array('start' => 'start', 'prev' => 'prev', 'next' => 'next') : array();
    unset($attributes['rel']);

    $this->_attributes = '';
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
        $this->_attributes .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $value . '"';
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Add "rel" attribute
 *
 * @link    http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes
 * @param   string  $type
 * @return  string
 */
protected function _attr_rel($type) {
    if (isset($this->_link_types[$type])) {
        unset($this->_link_types[$type]);
        return ' rel="' . $type . '"';
    }

    return '';
}
```

}

And in Controller add

```
    $offset = $this->input->get('page') ? $this->input->get('page') : 0;
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url('admin/employees');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->employee->total_emp($filter_data);
    $config['per_page'] = 50;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Comment: in View print pagintion links like as <?php   echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>

Comment: never ever change core files in the system path - if you want to update your CI Version in the near future you would probably crash your application ... if you really want to change the behavior of core files read this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html